# How to create a drop shadow on a panel in windows form application using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a panel in my winform application for which I want to have is
a drop shadow. I tried to override `CreateParams`, but there was no success, I guess it only works in *Forms* and not in *Panels*.

this is what I did...

```
class SPanel : Panel
{
    public SPanel(): base()
    {}

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried thus far.  This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Comment: A possible option:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19258/Transparent-drop-shadow-in-C-GDI